# How to Connect to a Remote Queue Manager with IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer?

Tags: ibm-mq

I create a queue manager like QMTEST in IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer. I want to connect to a remote queue manager (remote ip address). I followed these steps:

- add remote Queue manager
- Queue manager name: QMTEST [Next]
- Host Name or ip Address: X.X.X.X(remote ip) [Finish]

But I couldn't connect. I got this error message 'Could not establish  connection to the queue manager-reason 2538.(AMQ4059)'. What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 5):

The four digit number in your error message is an MQRC (MQ Reason Code). This number gives you more information about what went wrong. You can look it up in Knowledge Center.

[MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE (2538)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q045380_.htm)

There is a list of possible things that could cause this error. My guess is it is likely to be the first one, you have not started a listener on the queue manager, since you do not mention doing that in your question details.

You should also read the following link which is some basic details on how to connect to a remote queue manager. You appear to have the MQ Explorer side sorted, but perhaps not the queue manager side.

[Setting up the server using the command line](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q009310_.htm)

Comment: "Create a user ID on the server that is not in the mqm group. This user ID must exist on the server and client. This is the user ID that the sample applications must be run as, otherwise a 2035 error is returned." How can I create User ID?

Comment: How you create a user ID varies from platform to platform. You don't tell us what platform. Also, a quick google search will tell you the answer quicker than waiting for responses on here!

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure the listener is running on the remote queue manager side. The default MQ listener port is 1414. If the listener is running then check the queue manager error logs for any connection errors from the MQ explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the qmgr and its listener are running and that you have a SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN channel?  That is the server-connection channel used for remote administration of a queue manager.  This [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21623113) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Is this on a modern Windows or Linux server?  If so, did you open the port (i.e. 1414) in the firewall?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when we create a Queue manager remote administration objects are not created that's why we get such errors because it is unable to find these objects. To create them right click on the queue Manager, Select Remote Administration objects and create them and start the listener.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same error and the queue was configured correctly. 
I was using Eclipse and switched to the MQ Explorer setup available from IBM web page. 
After that, I was totally able to see the queues and everything I was supposed to see.